# String permutation on linking trailing character

Tags: string, algorithm, language-agnostic

I'm writing a game for some highschool kids to learn about computer science/math in general.

But I'm also stuck in a question I've designed for myself, and want to see if there's a more efficient way to solve it.

The question:

Give a word "Abc" and a list of words ["Cat", "Tick", "Apple", "Orange", ... ]
Is it possible to construct a word chain in this condition where last character of the first word is same as the first character of any word chosen from the word list. And can this chain be successfully constructed by the given word list?  Return true if possible, false otherwise.

```
INPUT: boolean lastCharPermutation(String startingWord, String [] wordsList) { .. }

OUTPUT: true for able to complete the combination, false otherwise
```

For example,

**Case #1:**
Take `"Abc", ["Girl", "King", "Cat", "Dog", "Good", "Tick"]`
Return *true* because `Abc-Cat-Tick-King-Good-Dog-Girl`

**Case #2:**
Take `"Abc", ["Tour", "Game", "Cat", "Bridge", "Women", "Man"]`
Return *false* because `Abc-Cat-Tour` and stops there

Comment: Why is it labeled with 4 different languages? Is it actually meant to be language-agnostic?

Comment: Voting to close, I think this fails to be a real question (for this site).

Comment: well, I guess pseudo code is OK! Or a way to analyze this. I couldn't think of a way to do this efficiently.  and need help

Comment: @xbeta please show some attempts, you are just giving other people your assignment

Comment: You guys are right! It shouldn't be language specific.

Comment: @OP: also shouldn't "Case #2" be "Abc-Cat-Tour"?

Comment: @Craig Yes, will fix that! I'm typing from my note earlier! miss that!

Comment: @jamylak I actually come up with this question, but I'm having trouble to get it analyze. There's no way to do this efficiently, the best is to run the list N times, and construct a table which maps the first and ending character in a graph.

Comment: I can only think a solution using a graph that bind each word in the list with other words using the rule you describe, then using a DFS to traverse the graph starting in a point A without passing by the same node twice, if the graph has been fully traversed i.e. all the nodes have been marked as visited, then return `true` otherwise `false`. Based on this, I don't think this would be a good exercise for highschool students (or maybe it will?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is a [Eulerian Path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path)..
I had solved the same problem on [Codechef](http://www.codechef.com/problems/WORDS1).
This is my Code if you wanna use..
Plz tell me if you need a explanation,it is very easy to understand though.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int visit[26];
int adj[26][26];
int count=0;

void scc(int i) //Strongly COnnected Component
{
    visit[i]=-1;//visiting
    for(int t=0;t<26;t++)
    {
        if(adj[i][t]>0 && visit[t]==0)//not visited yet
        scc(t);
    }
    visit[i]=1;
    count++;
}

int main()
{
    string in;
    int t,n,k,nv,counta,countb,flag;
    int a[26],b[26];
    cin >> t;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin >> n;
        memset(a,0,26*sizeof(int));
        memset(b,0,26*sizeof(int));
        memset(visit,0,26*sizeof(int));
        memset(adj,0,26*26*sizeof(int));
        k=26;count=0;counta=0;countb=0;flag=0;nv=0;

        while(n > 0)
        {
            n--;
            cin >> in;
            a[in[0]-'a']++;
            b[in[in.size()-1]-'a']++;
            adj[in[0]-'a'][in[in.size()-1]-'a'] = 1;
            adj[in[in.size()-1]-'a'][in[0]-'a'] = 1;
        }

        for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
            if(a[i]>0)
            {
                scc(i);
                break;
            }

        for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
            if(a[i]!=0 || b[i]!=0)
                nv++;

        if(count!=nv)
            flag=1;     

        while(k > 0 && flag!=1  )
        {
            if(a[k-1]-b[k-1] == 1)
                counta++;
            else if(b[k-1]-a[k-1] == 1)
                countb++;
            else if(a[k-1]!=b[k-1])
                flag = 1;
            k--;
        }

        if(flag==0 && counta==countb && ( counta==1 || counta ==0))
            cout << "Ordering is possible." <<endl;
        else
            cout << "The door cannot be opened." <<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sure..do acept it,if it meets ur needs.